# iOS auto-renewable subscriptions and restoreCompletedTransactions(): is the transaction removed from the queue after expiration or cancellation?

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase, auto-renewing

After a long search for an answer, I want to ask a very simple question here. Are transactions associated with a auto-renewable subscription removed after the expiration date from the list of transactions that can be obtained using the `restoreCompletedTransactions()` method?

In its simplest implementation, is it possible to manage application content associated with a `auto-renewable subscription` without using `Validating Receipts`? And using only the result of the `restoreCompletedTransactions()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two questions here.

1) Are transactions associated with a auto-renewable subscription removed after the expiration date from the list of transactions that can be obtained using the restoreCompletedTransactions() method?

**Answer:**
**No.** Those entries will always **remain** there and when you validate the receipt, you will get it back in response. By Doing the **Restore purchase** won't delete the **existing entries** from receipt. When you testing the In app purchase with Sandbox account then you will have 35 mins to use that account within 8 Hours. You can do whatever you want. You can do subscription again(In this case system will say us that your subscription is still running). After 35 mins of first purchased, Plan will be considered as Cancel and you need to do Subscription again(Only in Sandbox mode, Well In production mode May be it will not ask to do subscription again? I am not sure here.)

2) Is it possible to manage application content associated with a auto-renewable subscription without using Validating Receipts

**Answer:** **No.** Its good to use the receipt validation for **locking/unlocking** content of your application.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The android implementation has a similar `queryPurchases()` method. Google Play returns the purchases made by the user account logged in to the device. If the request is successful, the Play Billing Library stores the query results in a List of Purchase objects. Only active subscriptions appear on this list. As long as the in-app product is on this list, the user should have access to it. It is strange that in ios everything is much more complicated.

Comment: @denri11, Yeah some points regarding IAP in iOS is strange. But in the receipt validation, you can use the latest_receipt key for further validation and for latest purchased history. As we talked about IAP, let me share one more important thing that many developer faces commonly. Please finish transaction after you got success/fail response. Otherwise it will cause some issues in app.